# organic groups and private files

Tags: organic-groups, files

Hi everyone I was wondering if it's possible to have directories of files attached to an organic group so that only group members and admins can access those files. If so whats the easiest way to accomplish this? I tried to use a htaccess file in files/private/groups (the directory I want to store these files in) but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone attempting something similar I ultimately modified the [user files module](http://drupal.org/project/user_files)
and used the hook_file_download to only allow group members to download protected content by using the built in is_og_group_member function.