# D7 Organic groups and securing private files

Tags: organic-groups, files, security, users

I'm looking for a current solution for private file protection in D7 (so files uploaded without a node can be hidden from unauthorized users). I saw this question, [organic groups and private files](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63884/organic-groups-and-private-files), but it's solution is pointing to a project for D6. Is there a D7 solution out there?

Comment: I am not sure if this is "the" solution, but I found this project that appears to hint at being a solution, modified from another project that deals with the same issue (I believe):  http://drupal.org/project/private_files_download_permission
  
(If anyone has input, feel free to comment, and thanks in advance)

Comment: This wasn't the solution, as it uses roles, and not the group id. I need the group id to manage access to the file. Any thoughts?